# node.js async: Last callback function is not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async.js

I am following [MDN tutorials for web development](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs) and following all steps given there. Everything was working correctly till [part 4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes), but in part 5 after changing my code as per [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Displaying_data/Home_page#Controller), the site is not responding.

I've just copy pasted all code so there should not any mistake on my part.

After putting console.log() statements in the code, I found that the last callback function is not being called.

Original code as given in tutorial was:

```
var Book = require('../models/book');
var Author = require('../models/author');
var Genre = require('../models/genre');
var BookInstance = require('../models/bookinstance');

var async = require('async');

exports.index = function(req, res) {   

    async.parallel({
        book_count: function(callback) {
            Book.count({}, callback); // Pass an empty object as match condition to find all documents of this collection
        },
        book_instance_count: function(callback) {
            BookInstance.count({}, callback);
        },
        book_instance_available_count: function(callback) {
            BookInstance.count({status:'Available'}, callback);
        },
        author_count: function(callback) {
            Author.count({}, callback);
        },
        genre_count: function(callback) {
            Genre.count({}, callback);
        },
    }, function(err, results) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Local Library Home', error: err, data: results });
    });
};
```

For debugging I changed it as:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    console.log("Book controller index called");   

    async.parallel({
        book_count: function(callback) {
            console.log("Book controller book_count called");
            //Book.count({}, callback); // Pass an empty object as match condition to find all documents of this collection
            Book.count({}, function(err, count){
                callback(err, count);
            });
            console.log("Book controller book_count ended");
        },
        book_instance_count: function(callback) {
            console.log("Book controller book_instance_count called");
            //BookInstance.count({}, callback);
            BookInstance.count({}, function(err, count){
                callback(err, count);
            });
            console.log("Book controller book_instance_count ended");
        },
        book_instance_available_count: function(callback) {
            console.log("Available books count called");
            //BookInstance.count({status:'Available'}, callback);
            BookInstance.count({status:'Available'}, function(err, count){
                callback(err, count);
            });
            console.log("Available books count ended.");
        },
        author_count: function(callback) {
            console.log("Author count called.");
            //Author.count({}, callback);
            Author.count({}, function(err, count){
                callback(err, count);
            });
            console.log("Author count ended.");
        },
        genre_count: function(callback) {
            console.log("Genre count called.");
            //Genre.count({}, callback);
            Genre.count({}, function(err, count){
                callback(err, count);
            });
            console.log("Genre count ended.");
        },
    }, function(err, results) {
        console.log("Book controller render called");
        res.render('index', { title: 'Local Library Home', error: err, data: results });
    });
};
```

But it didn't change anything, i.e. site was still not responding.

console.log() logs are:

> Book controller index called 
>   Book controller book_count called  
>   Book controller book_count ended      
>   Book controller book_instance_count called 
>   Book controller book_instance_count ended
>   Available books count called
>   Available books count ended.    
>   Author count called.                  
>   Author count ended.                       
>   Genre count called.                           
>   Genre count ended.

Project upto tutorial part 4 is [here](https://github.com/gaurishg)

As suggested by Amir, I put log() inside the callback function:

```
book_count: function(callback) {
            console.log("Book controller book_count called");
            //Book.count({}, callback); // Pass an empty object as match condition to find all documents of this collection
            Book.count({}, function(err, count){
                console.log("before book count callback");
                callback(err, count);
                console.log("after book count callback");
            });
            console.log("Book controller book_count ended");
        }
```

Console logs are still same, i.e. `console.log("before book count callback");` and `console.log("after book count callback");` are not being called.

Comment: can you put all of your `console.log("something ended.")`s inside the other callback when you do `callback(err, count);` and see what it prints?

Comment: I am guessing the view file `/views/index.pug` is missing.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ Do you mean the last callback function (err, results)?

Comment: @BrahmaDev View file is there. Code is not even reaching upto render(). See the log() statement before render() is not being executed.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. And @Aᴍɪʀ meant that you should put `console.log`  above each `callback(err, count)`

Comment: exactly as @BrahmaDev said, you need to log when you actually call `callback(err, count')`, just move all of your logs two lines up, except the very last one.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ @BrahmaDev Thanks for the suggestion. I put `console.log` there but that function is not being called. I've added that part in the question.

Comment: Actually, the problem was is the connection with MongoDB, after sorting that out, it worked.

Comment: i'm glad that you have figured it out :)

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ Thanks again for your suggestion of putting `console.log` in the right place. I could figure it out only because of this.